# Chrome Console : How to edit sqllite database?

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, console

I created a database using html5 and i can see this in Chrome's console but I can't edit them.  Is there a way to do this in console? I want to populate and modify the table.  Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on the database name in the Resource tab, a console appears to the right with a prompt. There you can start typing sql.